# laravel function ::with is not generating the correct sql

Tags: laravel

I have the following query in Laravel 4:

```
    Tasks::with('tasks_status')
```

and generate the following sqls:

```
    select * from `tasks`
    select * from `tasks_status` where `tasks_status`.`status` in (2, 0)
```

The connection in models is well done.
The "tasks_status" table have values from 1 to 7 (as id's).
The "tasks" table return values for statuses from 1 to 7.

The second sql shouldn't be?
        select * from `tasks_status` where `tasks_status`.`status` in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

Thank you.

Comment: I would suggest posting the whole query, and the model relationships for both Task ands TasksStatus models.

Comment: I would guess `Task` belongsTo `TaskStatus` and you have 2 types of tasks, but one of them has `0` or `null` as a foreign key, so the queries are correct in the end..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved. I made the incorrect keys relations.
Thank you for your time.